# Delphi distributed building failure

Tags: delphi, jenkins, build, distributed, spring4d

I've created a tiny project [0] to reproduce an error in a controlled environment. The facts, I'm using jenkins to build my project, a big one, I'd like to make some parallel builds. Let me make it graphically

```
[MyBasicPackage] -----> [MyPackageTester] ------> [MyBasicApp]
      .
      .
      +-----> [...]
      +-----> [...]
```

this is the organization I've made on [0], I have a class **TMyUnit** (**MyBasicPackage**) registered on spring container to be tested. I build it and generate its .dcu, .bpl, and so on.
The second stage I build my **MyPackageTester** that requires **MyBasicPackage**. Finally I build the app that requires **MyPackageTester**. So far so good.

When I try to build my **MyBasicPackage** on, say **PC-00**, get the artifacts and try to build the the **MyPackageTester** on **PC-06** (same arch, same OS, same IDE, same spring4d version), and a nice error arise:

```
Unit TMyUnit was compiled with a different version of Spring.Container.Registration
```

so, I update my spring4d on both machines (**PC-00** and **PC-06**) and build them. Run... and same error arise.
check the library path options (*C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Componentes\spring4d\Library\DelphiXE6\Win32\Debug*), delete dcu files and build them once again on both machines, same error.
copy dcu files from **PC-00** to **PC-06** to avoid any kind of system configuration and the same error arise.

Probably I'm trying to do something that's not possible so far. I've googled a couple of days without luck.

Any ideas?

Please feel free to fork or pull request the example ;)

Regards

[0] https://github.com/graguirre/DelphiDepencyExample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to build with the Spring.Core runtime package. Not only will that prevent this error but your code will actually work.

If you do not then all modules will hold their own version of the GlobalContainer instance you are using and nothing will work.

Comment: For any reason I couldn't link dynamically into the IDE, I've created a makefile and it works smooth. I've created a 3rd party units directory to keep spring's DCUs and just adding -LUSpring.Core to my building options compiler links Spring.Core's lib dynamically. I've updated this solution to my github repo https://github.com/graguirre/DelphiDepencyExample

Comment: Binary files that can be recreated by the sources should never be stored in a VCS but whatever.

Comment: I'll try to checkout spring, build it and link with my little project.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one solution is put all your libraries in a centralized repository and pull them to compile your projects. It should resolve the different version error.

Comment: This will solve the compile error but not the functional defect.

Comment: How do you build another package with a runtime package?

Comment: You add the package to the requires clause in the dpk